# Possible to go back to the state I was in before running 'git rebase --abort'

Tags: git

Long-story-short, I was in the middle of developing on a branch and didn't know that I was in the middle of a rebase. When I was done developing on the branch and saw `REBASE 1/1` and then ran `git rebase --abort` and now I seem to have lost all my changes. Is there any way I can essentially undo that last action?

Comment: I find it hard to understand how did you end up losing any changes while doing a rebase.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your reflog, `git reflog`. You can get back to where you were before you started the rebase if somehow you wind up on some other commit. You haven't lost everything, don't panic. Once you find where you want to get back to in the reflog, do a `git reset --hard HEAD@{xx}` and find the XX number in the reflog. Note this this will overwrite things in your current dir, so just in case you have changes you want, you should stash them, but your active branch should now point to that commit where you wanted to be at and your working dir & index should be consistent with that commit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have committed your changes, before running `git rebase --abort`, you can find those commits with `git reflog`.

Uncommitted changes at the time of `git rebase --abort` are irrevocably lost.